# Prevent from converting string to int in xaxis in plot by groups

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to make a grouped plot with `matplotlib.pyplot` library in `Python`. I want to have date signature as a `string`, presented on x-axis. Despite I defined its values ("day_date" column) as `string`, the resulted plot keeps displaying the values as int-s.

**How to have the x-axis values displayed as string?** (Please note I do not want to have them converted into any dedicated date-format).

```
# Define data frame 
day_date = ['20151103', '20151103', '20151103', '20151103', '20151103', '20151103', '20151104', '20151104', '20151104', '20151104', '20151104', '20151104', '20151105', '20151105', '20151105', '20151105', '20151105', '20151105', '20151106', '20151106', '20151106', '20151106', '20151106', '20151106', '20151107', '20151107', '20151107', '20151107', '20151107', '20151107', '20151108', '20151108', '20151108', '20151108', '20151108', '20151108']
country_code = ['BY', 'DE', 'ID', 'PL', 'RU', 'US', 'BY', 'DE', 'ID', 'PL', 'RU', 'US', 'BY', 'DE', 'ID', 'PL', 'RU', 'US', 'BY', 'DE', 'ID', 'PL', 'RU', 'US', 'BY', 'DE', 'ID', 'PL', 'RU', 'US', 'BY', 'DE', 'ID', 'PL', 'RU', 'US']
val = [35989, 64488, 72879, 73586, 192538, 54474, 137322, 227274, 307893, 249741, 683455, 288863, 179319, 287662, 455944, 321588, 854791, 342946, 207263, 326290, 558362, 361792, 981566, 390313, 224863, 369141, 637215, 415884, 1031772, 429145, 272623, 419612, 702541, 497348, 1160243, 462813]

df_tmp = pd.DataFrame([day_date, country_code, val]).T
df_tmp.columns = ['day_date','country_code','val']
df_tmp.head()    

# Plot 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in df_tmp.groupby('country_code'):
    ax.plot(group.day_date, group.val, label=name)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nor really clear what you want to do. You have to give `plt` some information about where to put the points, i.e. x-values. Strings do not fulfil this requirement. Can there be multiple entries per day? If not you could do something like this:

```
dates = sorted(list(set(day_date)))
# Plot 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in df_tmp.groupby('country_code'):
    xvals = [dates.index(d) for d in group.day_date]
    ax.plot(xvals, group.val, label=name)

plt.xticks(range(len(dates)),dates,rotation = 45)
```

Comment: Thank you tomas! That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is you are using strings, which cannot be easily interpreted without getting the interpretation wrong.  You should convert from string to datetime

```
import datetime as dt
from pylab import *

strp = dt.datetime.strptime

day_date = ['20151103', '20151103', '20151103', '20151103', '20151103', '20151103', '20151104', '20151104', '20151104', '20151104', '20151104', '20151104', '20151105', '20151105', '20151105', '20151105', '20151105', '20151105', '20151106', '20151106', '20151106', '20151106', '20151106', '20151106', '20151107', '20151107', '20151107', '20151107', '20151107', '20151107', '20151108', '20151108', '20151108', '20151108', '20151108', '20151108']
day_date = [strp(r,'%Y%m%d') for r in day_date]
```

Now when you plot the x-ticks are labeled with datetime strings as opposed to integers.

You can read more about controlling datetime tick-labels [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html)

Comment: Thanks tnknepp! This basically does work. I picked @thomas solution as I wanted to have it done without converting from string to datetime.